# Going to lists within lists witha for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hello I want the for loop to go through all the 3 lists within the `main_list` and add 10 to all the values within lists `bar_positions, Max_profit , Max_drawdown`, any help is appreciated :).

```
x_indexes= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
bar_positions= [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]
Max_profit= [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]
Max_drawdown= [1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
main_list = [bar_positions, Max_profit,Max_drawdown]
k=0
for x,y in zip(x_indexes,main_list[k]): #Goes through [bar_positions, Max_profit,Max_drawdown]
      y += 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use itertools for this:

```
from itertools import chain

x = chain.from_iterable((bar_positions, Max_profit, Max_drawdown))
main_list = [i + 10 for i in x]
```

Or do you want a list of lists as a result?

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete what you were writing see below:

Code:

```
x_indexes= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
bar_positions= [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]
Max_profit= [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]
Max_drawdown= [1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
main_list = [bar_positions, Max_profit, Max_drawdown]
k=0
for k in range(len(main_list)):
    for x in x_indexes:
        main_list[k][x] += 10
            
print(main_list)
```

Output:

```
[[20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80], [11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23], [11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make one list comprehension instead all those lines of code:

```
main_list= [[x+7 for x in l] for l  in main_list]
```

Or if you want it flattened (return one list as result):

```
main_list= [x+7 for l  in main_list for x in l]
```